# Getting Green Image while Preview Hidden Live Video

Tags: android, android-camera, live-streaming, yuv

I want to stream live video from Android phone to a video stream server like [Ant Media Server](https://github.com/ant-media/Ant-Media-Server). The problem is that I get Green Image preview in the live video server.

**The code parts which I get the error**:

1. I have changed [Yasea](https://github.com/begeekmyfriend/yasea) (live broadcaster for Android) in order to hide camera preview in activity (so can be record from everywhere). The idea of hiding the camera is adopted from [Android Hidden Camera] (https://github.com/kevalpatel2106/android-hidden-camera).
2. After hiding camera preview, I got the audio packages in the video stream server, but I did not get any video frame, which I realized I have to get my own picture frames and send to the live broadcaster server. Therefore, I have implemented the Camera.PreviewCallback in [SRSCameraView](https://github.com/begeekmyfriend/yasea/blob/master/library/src/main/java/net/ossrs/yasea/SrsCameraView.java).
3. In `onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera)`, I've got the NV21 image data and converted it to YuvImage as below:

   ```
   YuvImage yuv = new YuvImage(data, camera.getParameters().getPreviewFormat(), camera.getParameters().getPreviewSize().width, camera.getParameters().getPreviewSize().height, null);
   mGLPreviewBuffer.asIntBuffer().put(convertData2IntBuffer(yuv.getYuvData()));
   mPrevCb.onGetNV21Frame(mGLPreviewBuffer.array(), yuv.getWidth(), yuv.getHeight());
   ```
4. After that, I've put the YuvData into the preview buffer of the streamer, and implemented the buffer receiver:

   ```
   public void onGetNV21Frame(byte[] data, int width, int height) {
       calcSamplingFps();
       if (!sendAudioOnly) {
           mEncoder.onGetYuvNV21Frame(data, width, height, new Rect(0, 0, width, height));
       }
   }
   ```
5. The code for [mEncoder](https://github.com/begeekmyfriend/yasea/blob/master/library/src/main/java/net/ossrs/yasea/SrsEncoder.java) is taken from Yasea.
6. Now I got the live (and hidden camera) video (and audio) in the live streamer but got Green Image as displayed below:

This is what I get in Ant Media Server:
[image: Green Android Camera Live Stream Preview]

Please help me in solving this issue. Thanks.

Comment: Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Thanks. The problem is that the code is very dirty and I want to publish it as library. Therefore, there is not possible code sample.

Comment: Sorry, then there is no way to know what’s wrong.

Comment: OK. I will publish after making it more readable. Till tomorrow. Thanks for your attention.

Comment: Dear @szatmary I've tried to make the error more clear. Please notify me if there is any problem remained. Sorry for the mistakes, as I'm a new user in stackoverflow.

Comment: I've published the code as a library in: https://github.com/mirsamantajbakhsh/LiveHiddenCamera/